# Looping through UIImageViews to see if any view overlap the other view in the array

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop, uiimageview

With an NSArray of UIImageViews, how do I check to see if any of the views intersect. My attempt is below. The error reads, "Property 'frame' not found on object type 'id'".

```
- (BOOL)isOverlapping:(UIImageView*)image
{
    for (int x = 0; x < objectsArray.count; x++)
    {
        if([objectsArray[x] isEqual:image])continue;
        if([objectsArray[x] isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
            if(CGRectIntersectsRect(image.frame, (UIImageView)objectsArray[x].frame))
                return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the cast around parenthesis:

```
((UIImageView *)objectsArray[x]).frame
```

Comment: Thank you! Too much time spent on Swift has my head straying away from asterisks.